# Live Xcode's Interface Builder UIView subclass (IB_DESIGNABLE) without drawRect:

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, ibdesignable

Is it possible to create a `UIView` subclass that renders live in Xcode (by adding the `IB_DESIGNABLE` attribute as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html)) but doesn't have a custom `drawRect:` method?

We have a custom `UIView` subclass that uses some `CAShapeLayer`s which are added to `self.layer` for drawing (hence, there's no need to override `drawRect:`). This class works fine on the App, but won't render on Xcode.

If we replicate the code in `drawRect:` it works, but we'd prefer to keep the drawing to happen automatically on the layers.

Can this be done?

---

I also tried doing

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, self.myLayer1.frame.origin.x, self.myLayer1.frame.origin.y);
    [self.myLayer1 renderInContext:currentContext];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, self.myLayer1.frame.origin.x, self.myLayer1.frame.origin.y);
    [self.myLayer2 renderInContext:currentContext];    
}
```

which seems to work on the device but not on Xcode's IB.

Comment: Ensure your initializing(i.e. setting up `CAShapeLayers`) codes are also called from `initWithFrame:`. IB calls that for previewing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm calling it from there as well. No luck. How do you know that IB uses `initWithFrame:`? Is there anyway of debugging the view's code when IB is previewing it?

Comment: `Editor` > `Debug Selected Views` from Xcode menu.

Comment: Debug Selected Views makes Xcode crash with my custom view. :-(

Comment: I submitted both the crash and the CALayer live rendering issue as bug reports to Apple.

Answer (score 4):

You can preview `UIView` subclasses in IB (with the `IB_DESIGNABLE` macro) **even if the `drawRect:` isn't overridden**.
I added your [code](https://gist.github.com/rsanchezsaez/ac620ce58bd6097207d8) in XCode 6.1 and added a `OEProgressIndicator` into a `xib` file. Then I debugged it (using menu `Editor` / `Debug Selected View` ) by setting a breakpoint in your `commonProgressIndicatorInit` selector.

*Here's why you don't see anything in the preview with your current code*: **when the `commonProgressIndicatorInit` is invoked (from the `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` constructor), the `frame` is equal to `CGRectZero`** (`x:0 y:0 width:0 height:0`) so that your center variable is actually equal to `(0, 0)` and radius is `-1`.
On the device, depending on the way the class is used, you may be directly invoked with the proper frame, that's why it may work on the device but not in IB.

*To fix this, I would implement the [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) selector* (override it from `UIView`) to organise properly the sublayers. This selector is going to be invoked when the `frame` is going to change from `CGRectZero` to the proper values set in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the method `- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder` in order to tell IB to live render a view.

See here: [Creating a Live View of a Custom Object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html)

Also, you guys are right that this feature is also available for Objective-C.

You don't necessarily need to use `drawRect`, you can try using `- (void)layoutSubviews`, it seems to work. The problem with leaving code in places like `- (void)layoutSubviews` just for the sake of live rendering is that it may be less performant, etc (for instance you can do a lot of stuff in `- (void)awakeFromNib`, but that method does not get called from Live Rendering, so just make sure that you do all your set up in `- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder` as well.

Comment: This doesn't help to render custom CALayers that are sublayers of the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code, it's hard to see what the source of the problem is, but to answer your question, yes, you can use IBInspectable / IBDesignable without needing to implement any other specific method.  I have done this for a view that uses many layers and does not do any drawing (uses the nested layers for that).

For a quick test example snippet with rounded corners:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyView : UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
        get { return self.layer.cornerRadius }
        set { self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue    }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth:CGFloat {
        get { return self.layer.borderWidth }
        set { self.layer.borderWidth = newValue }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor {
        get { return UIColor(CGColor: self.layer.borderColor) }
        set { self.layer.borderColor = newValue.CGColor }
    }
}
```

For a simple example that does gradients, see [this post](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/UrQFJb).

For an explanation on how to debug the live views, refer to WWDC §411 at about the 22 minute mark.

The only limitation that I have seen so far is that you can add inspectable properties in class extensions, but they only render properly on the device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but [this class](https://gist.github.com/rsanchezsaez/ac620ce58bd6097207d8) we made doesn't work at all. If you manage to make it display on Xcode 6, please tell me how. See the two `drawRect` workaround implementations we tried, to no avail.

Comment: It is a Swift only feature - to my knowledge.  Start with the link that I posted as a baseline, and branch from there.

Comment: `IB_DESIGNABLE` custom views is not a Swift only feature. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html) clearly state that it works with Objective-C as well. If only, the fact that this doesn't work with custom child CALayers is an *Objective-C only* bug. I [reported it](http://bugreport.apple.com) to Apple.

Comment: Ah, well at least you have a good work-around then - to use Swift.

Comment: Using Swift in our production environment is not an option for now.